# Disable auto-closing of brackets in Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

How can I disable auto closing of specific brackets?
I have a java mode active and Monaco is auto closing '<' to '<>'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the editor option [`autoClosingBrackets`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditoroptions.html#autoclosingbrackets)

```js
/**
 * Enable auto closing brackets.
 * Defaults to true.
 */
autoClosingBrackets?: boolean;
```

You can use this option in the creation options or later:

```js
// When creating the editor
var editor = monaco.editor.create(container, { autoClosingBrackets: false });

// -----------------------
// Changing the option at a later time
var editor = monaco.editor.create(container);
// ...
editor.updateOptions({ autoClosingBrackets: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer., yet, this disables ALL auto-close brackets unfortunately. I have found bug in the language definition of JAVA where '<' was set as auto close bracket. I removed it and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the language definition of JAVA, where < was set to autoclose. I had to remove that definition and all was working ok.